# Is there a way to exclude a character(s) from the SQL wildcard %?

Tags: sql, wildcard, sql-like

I am attempting to do file searches with SQL. I need to keep the searches within the directory I am doing the comparisons against. When doing a LIKE or NOT LIKE comparison in SQL, the wildcard '%' is used to represent 0, 1, or many characters. Are there ways to exclude or delimit characters involved in that wildcard search? I need to do a comparison like the following:

```
LIKE 'C:/Data/%.txt'
```

However, I do not want the '%' to find any records where there is a slash '/' character involved in the wildcard search. I would want it to return examples like:

```
C:/Data/file1.txt
C:/Data/records_2017.txt
C:/Data/listing#7.txt
```

But I do NOT want the wildcard to find records with slash in it, because in my situation, it goes beyond the current folder I am interested in doing file searches in:

```
C:/Data/OtherFolder/file1.txt
C:/Data/System/SomethingElse/records_2016.txt
```

The above examples would be returned, because everything between the slash after Data and the .txt extension is all free game for the wildcard. I do NOT want the above examples to be returned in my wildcard search.

I tried doing character sets, such as [^/], but it seems to only work to exclude strings BEGINNING with a slash '/' character. I need to prevent wildcard from using a slash ANYWHERE in the string.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this with a single LIKE, but you could do this:

```
WHERE MyColumn LIKE 'C:/Data/%.txt'
AND MyColumn NOT LIKE 'C:/Data/%/%.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support some form of regular expressions.  For instance:

```
col regexp '^C:/Data/[^/]?.txt$'
```

The specific match operator/function varies by database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle, you can use `REGEXP_LIKE` instead of `LIKE` for finer control of what records will match. Check [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) for details on how to use it.